# The realm dot net base example does not compile

Tags: realm, fody

I am having trouble at getting the example "QuickJournal" to compile on iOS. The code compiles OK, but fails during the Fody step.

### Goals

Try out the example application for .NET through the following
- Pull the repository
- Open the solution in examples/QuickJournal
- Compile and test

### Expected Results

Smooth compilation & testing experience

### Actual Results

Fody out of memory exception

### Steps to Reproduce

See the setup, follow steps
I am using the latest Xamarin/Visual Studio Mac/XCode

### Code Sample

The regular realm source code

### Version of Realm and Tooling

git clone https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet.git

git checkout 8f5e36ffd91e06b9c60b91f9de3fb312b411a4a4

The exception I am getting is
Fody: Found debug symbols at '~/realm-dotnet/examples/QuickJournal/QuickJournal/obj/Debug/QuickJournal.pdb'.
    MSBUILD : error : Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
    MSBUILD : error : Exception:
    MSBUILD : error : Out of memory
    MSBUILD : error : StackTrace:
    MSBUILD : error :   at (wrapper alloc) System.Object:AllocVector (intptr,intptr)
    MSBUILD : error :   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.MsfDirectory..ctor (Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbReader reader,

See log file
[RealmCompilelog.txt](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/files/906913/RealmCompilelog.txt)

Comment: I have no problems compiling it. I suggest you open a Github issue, as a StackOverflow is a poor place to file bug reports. When you open the issue, be sure to share what platforms/devices you are targeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm 1.2.1 addresses that by using an updated version of Fody.

*Answer for older Realm versions*:
This is caused by a [Cecil bug](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/378) with Mono 5.0. As Realm depends on Fody, which uses Cecil, compilation will fail for project referencing it. Until new Cecil and Fody versions are released, the workaround is to revert to Mono 4.8:

[image]